# Pgfplots bars between the x ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0,988
4,840
8,520
12,1495
16,1048
20,729
24,1952
28,1881
32,2233
36,5542
40,1855
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Aniket Bhadane

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    xlabel=Months,
    ylabel=Emails,
    grid=both,
    xtick distance = 4,
    ytick distance = 1000,
]
\addplot[ybar,fill] table [x, y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The generated output is:

[image]

But what I want is (Notice the X-axis ticks):

[image]

I want to have the bars to fall between the X-axis ticks. The vertical grid lines should be on the ticks, not centered on the bars. How can I do it?

Comment: Where do you want the vertical grid lines? Centered on the bars, as your last image, or on the ticks?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hi, I want them on the ticks, not centered on the bars

Answer (score 4):

For this case you can simply add 2 to the x-value, by saying

```
\addplot[ybar,fill] table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}+2, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
```

Note `x expr`, which lets you specify some mathematical expression. `\thisrowno` grabs the value from the specified column number, where the column counting starts at zero.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0,988
4,840
8,520
12,1495
16,1048
20,729
24,1952
28,1881
32,2233
36,5542
40,1855
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    xlabel=Months,
    ylabel=Emails,
    grid=both,
    xtick distance = 4,
    ytick distance = 1000,
]
\addplot[ybar,fill] table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}+2, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Include the following lines to the options of the axis environment:

`x tick label as interval = true,
xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\nexttick}$},`

This produces the following output:

[image: Barplot]

Comment: Thanks. But I want the vertical grid lines on the ticks, not centered on the bars